# Laravel Package's Controller does not exsist

Tags: exception, laravel, reflection, controller, package

I have a Laravel 4.2 application.In this I have my workbench folder with two packages. One package is vehicle package.I have attached the structure of the package with this.
In the package routes.php I have a route :

```
Route::get('/vehicles', array(
    'as' => 'vehicles', 'uses' => 'VehicleController@index'
    )
);
```

For this route I have a `index()` method in `VehicleController.php`

Note : In `the config/app.php` I have added the `VehicleServiceProvider.php`

When I run the application with `localhost/Application_Root/public/vehicles` it redirects to the root properly , but gives a Reflection Exception "VehicleController does not exsist."

Can anyone please help me on this?
Thank you in advance!

Vehicle package structure:

```
Vehicle
     -public
     - src
          -config
          -controllers
          -Vendor
                 -Vehicle
                         -Controllers
                         -Models
                         -Repositories
                          VehicleServiceProvider.php
          -migrations
          -views
     -test
     -vendor
          -routes.php
```

Comment: You will have to add you namespace to your controller like this `yourNamespace\Vehicle\Controllers\VehicleController@index`

Comment: when I add route : Route::get('/vehicles', 'Vendor\Vehicle\Controllers\VehicleController@index'); still it gives the error classs Vendor\Vehicle\Controllers\VehicleController does not exsist

Comment: Did you run `php artisan optimize`?